# TYPO3 Slug: Change fallbackCharacter

Tags: typo3, slug, typo3-9.x

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.19

By default, the urls look like this: xxx-yyy-zzzz/

How can I change, so it will be with underscore instead: xxx_yyy_zzzz/ ?

Is it the fallbackCharacter in Slug that needs to be changed?

But where and how do I make a general replacement on the whole site ?

Answer (score 1):

Create `typo3conf/ext/myext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php` and add:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['slug']['config']['fallbackCharacter'] = '_';
```

See

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html#manipulating-generated-slugs
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html#fallbackcharacter